# Square of the density operator for a mixed state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator

Consider a density operator $\hat{\rho}$ for a mixed state defined by
$$\hat{\rho} = \sum_k p_k |\psi_k\rangle \langle\psi_k|$$
Here $p_k$ is the probability of finding the $k$th system of the ensemble in the normalised state $|\psi_k \rangle$.

I wish to show for the mixed state that $\hat{\rho}^2 \neq \hat{\rho}$. Please note that in this question I am not trying to show that $\operatorname{tr}(\hat{\rho}^2) < \operatorname{tr}(\hat{\rho}) = 1$.

For the square of the density operator, I have:
\begin{align}
\hat{\rho}^2 &= \left (\sum_k p_k |\psi_k\rangle \langle\psi_k| \right ) \left (\sum_n p_n |\psi_n\rangle \langle\psi_n| \right )\\
&= \sum_{k,n} p_k p_n |\psi_k\rangle \langle\psi_k| \psi_n\rangle \langle\psi_n|
\end{align}
Now no assumption concerning the orthogonality of the states $|\psi_k\rangle$ and $|\psi_n\rangle$ has been made, so I cannot simply assume that: $\langle \psi_k| \psi_n \rangle = \delta_{kn}$. I could of course expand both of the states $|\psi_k\rangle$ and $|\psi_n\rangle$ in terms of a common set of basis states, but then I start to lose my way in a thicket of sums.

So my question is, is there a simple (or elegant) way to show that for a mixed state $\hat{\rho}^2 \neq \hat{\rho}$?

Comment: $\rho$ is hermitian and so diagonalizable. So you can choose to work an orthonormal basis in which $\rho$ is diagonal. Why make your life hard? (And while we are at it $\mathrm{tr}(A) \ne \mathrm{tr}(B)$ implies $A\ne B$)

Comment: @By Symmetry Ah, yes. Why make life so hard. Thanks for that.

Comment: Decompose it along its basis of eigenvectors and the thesys trivially follws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume, for example, that the states $|\psi_k\rangle$ are mutually orthogonal. In an orthonormal basis including the $|\psi_k\rangle$, $\rho$ is diagonal and its elements are the $p_k$. To obtain $\rho^2$, we simply replace matrix elements $p_k$ by $p^2_k$ . Relations $\rho^2\neq \rho$ and $tr(\rho^2) \le 1$ then follow from the fact that the $p_k$ are always less than 1 and $\Sigma p_k^2 \le (\Sigma p_k)^2$  (except in the particular case where only one of them is non-zero: the pure case).

Source : QUANTUM MECHANICS, Volume I : Basic Concepts, Tools, and Applications, by Claude Cohen-Tannoudji, Bernard Diu, and Franck Laloë
, Translated from the French by Susan Reid Hemley, Nicole Ostrowsky, and Dan Ostrowsky